# Advice Needed For Database Model - Partial EER Attached

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, database-design, mysql-workbench

I started to learn cakephp 3 and this is going to be my learning project.
The idea of application is that each user can have many products and the users can trade products between them.
Workflow:

- So one user can visits the profile of another user and he can click button trade. This will show all products of both users but separately per user.
- User can now select on one or more of his products and he must also select one or more another users products to start a trade
- Another user will get notified that he has trade offer and he will have to respond. He can now select accept, reject, or change trade
- If accepted trade gets "locked down"
- If rejected trade gets "locked down"
- If user clicks on change trade, he then, must reselect his and other users products and submit. This is where we return to point 3

This is my DB design so far, but i think it's not the best solution, so i put my hopes on you guys to suggest me better solution if you have one
[image: Db design]

If i summarise everything up. 
When trade happens i need to know who is trading what (multiple products) with who and which turn is it to accept, reject or reselect trade products. I'm also searching maybe for more meaningful names of my columns. Since on on some point roles of users gets changed and the one who was requesting products is now pending and vice versa.

If you need any additional informations please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: An aside:  [_Advice on many:many schema_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: What will be with user products after trade? I mean if user 1 had products A, B, C and user 2 had products D, E. And trade was between products A, B and D, E. So, after successful trade will user 1 have D, E, C products and user 2 - A, B?

Comment: And what "locked down" means? Perhaps, trade products are locked for another new trades until the trade will be accepted or rejected.

Comment: 1. question... yes this is an idea
2. question... locked down means that this trade its over... exactly what you wrote... trade products are locked for another new trades until the trade will be rejected. If accepted products get swap between users...

Comment: Another question. Can trade be between different product numbers? For instance, trade between products A, B and products C, D, E (2 products for 3)?

Comment: yes, you can try to trade 1 product vs 10 if you want to. so it's n:n

Comment: In `products_users_trades` table `product_id` is a product from one user (owner) and `requested_product_id` a product from another user?

Comment: yes... But don't bother with that table, because its not ok if you wan't the workflow like we discoused in upper comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have also `products` table with columns `Id`, `user_id` and so on.

According to the last comments it seems your current schema doesn’t support trading 1 product to 10. To support this I’d like to recommend to replace table `products_users_trades` to `products_trades` with columns: `Id`, `product_id`, `trade_id`, `created_date`.

So, let’s consider your workflows adding some steps I think could be and how your schema will be used:

1.For user to show trade(s) with its products:

```
select t.id, p.name, t.user_id, t.user_id1 from trades as t
inner join product_trades as pt 
  on t.user_id = pt.trade_id or t.user_id1 = pt.trade_id
inner join products as p on p.id = pt.product_id
where t.user_id = 1 or t.user_id1 = 1
```

Here you can use `t.user_id`, `t.user_id1` columns to determine what products are yours or not and offered by you or for you.

2.To show what products are available for trade:

```
select * from products as p
where p.user_id = 1 and p.id not in 
    (select pt.product_id from trades as t
    inner join product_trades as pt on t.id = pt.trade_id
    where t.status_id = 1 and (t.user_id = 1 or t.user_id1 = 1))
```

Here status_id = 1 means a new, locked trade. To release lock you need to change status to accepted or rejected.

3.To create a trade:

```
-- create a trade
insert into trades (status_id, user_id, user_id1) values (1, 1, 2);
-- insert all products in trade
insert into product_trades (product_id, trade_id) values (1, 1);
insert into product_trades (product_id, trade_id) values (1, 2);
```

4.To check if user can accept or reject a trade – check if this trade has user_id1 = his user id

5.To accept or reject trade – change trade status.

6.To modify trade - change trade modify data and remove all `product_trades` and create new ones. If you need to show changed products in trade then you need to delete only changed products and column `created_date` will be identifier that this is a new product.